# Enable HTML Tags in Wordpress Post excerpt

Tags: posts, excerpt

i did enyone know how i can enable HTML for the Post excerpt thet i can make some parts of thet big?

Sorry for my Bad english and thanks for awnser :)

Comment: I think [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151161/how-to-prevent-wordpress-from-stripping-html-tags-in-excerpt) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt) it reads:

> If adding the excerpt manually, you may use (some) HTML formatting and
>   the tags will not be stripped.

So if the only thing you want to do is make part of the text bigger, just add for instance:

```
example text <span class="bigger-text">example bigger text</span> some more normal text
```

And make font-size of .bigger-text larger than the normal.

Comment: Ok, If i Unserstand corectly, i have to create a class in adical CSS for this?

Comment: Exactly. Wrap the text you want to be bigger in a classed tag that you can apply CSS on

Comment: No its Dosent Work. :(

Comment: I've tested it and it works for me. Can you give more detail of what you're doing? My test: in a post, I've added the "Excerpt" metabox and wrote `Test <span class="test-class">test</span> test`. I added `<?php the_excerpt() ?>` on my single.php file because my theme doesn't show the excerpt by default. The excerpt is loaded in the frontend post as `<p>Test <span class="test-class">test</span> test</p>`

Comment: I make it too but i only See IT in normal Format. I think its a Problem of the theam. I View a litle bit in PHP..